# Maintaining button text state after page refresh using Vue.js and local storage

Tags: laravel, vue.js, local-storage

I am working on a task list using Vue.js component and Laravel, with a button to mark each individual task as "complete" or "incomplete". At the moment I can't even get it to change state, let alone maintain it after the page refresh. The console log says [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode".

CompleteButton.vue

```
<template>
<button type="button" @click="on_order_button_click()">
  {{ buttonText }}
</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props: ['userId', 'item'], required: true,
data() {
    return {
        item2: this.item
    }
},
methods: {
on_order_button_click() {
  this.item2.is_complete = !this.item2.is_complete;
  localStorage.setItem(this.item2.id, this.item2.is_complete);
}
},
mounted() {
var storedState = localStorage.getItem(this.item2.id);
if (storedState) {
  this.item2.is_complete = storedState;
}
},
computed: {
buttonText() {
  return this.item2.is_complete === true ? "Completed" : "Incomplete";
}

}
};
</script>
```

index.blade.php

```
 <complete-button user-id="{{ $user->id }}" item="{{ $item}}"></complete-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `item2` as `item` prop and which is readonly since it's passed as a property so `item2` keeping reference to the same readonly object.

You can simply use spread syntax or `Object.assign` method to create a new object.

```
item2: {...this.item}
```

*UPDATE :* As you commented, If it's a JSON string then simply parse it ans keep it as `item2`.

```
item2: JSON.stringify(this.item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try and pass "item" as an object I get [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected Object, got String with value "{"id":3,... in the console log

Comment: @jsmith then do a JSON parse `item2: JSON.parse(this.item)`